# click on button not execute function

Tags: javascript, html

- I try to click on btn3 ( kashef) and it's not triggering my function
  kashef()

  My code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/erezdav12/gn8shkrm/100/
- I need that by clicking on button kashef, my running counter (its a
  money counter) will subtract by, lets say, 300$ (cost of    clicking
  to get the feature) e.g: if money roller is in  1000$ on    the
  moment    of clicking event on "kashef" button, money counter reduce
  to 700 $    and continue running until the next clicking.

Here is the code:

```
    let start; 
    const el = document.getElementById('count');  
    const final = parseInt(el.textContent, 10);  
    const duration = 100000;  
    
    const kashefButton= document.getElementById("btn3");
    kashefButton.addEventListener("click", kashef);
    
    function kashef(){
    
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=1000-300;
    
    }
     
    
    const step = ts => {
      if (!start) {
        start = ts;
      }
       
      let progress = (ts - start) / duration;
      el.textContent = Math.floor(progress * final) * 100 ; 
      time = +el.textContent;
      if( progress < 1){
        requestAnimationFrame(step);
      }
    
      var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
      var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
      var btn3 = document.getElementById('btn3'); 
    
      const OpentButtons = 200;
    
    
      if (time <= OpentButtons) {
        btn1.disabled = true;
        btn2.disabled = true;
        btn3.disabled = true;
    
      } else {
        btn1.disabled = false;
        btn2.disabled = false;
        btn3.disabled = false;
      }
    
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

big thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a scoping issue.  The definition of kashdef is not defined in a scope that the event listener can find it in.  Move the definition of kashef outside of the ts block (right after "const duration = 100001;" ) and it works (verified in your fiddle).

Comment: Another thought is to use an in-line function for the event handler.  It does make the code a bit harder to read, but avoids scoping issues, especially if you are making this part of a larger project:

```
kashefButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
});
```

Comment: great david!!!thanks  it worked for my error on function definition.still ,click on kashef button not subtract from the rolling counter. any suggestions?

Comment: Your rolling counter is always set to the value of the current timestamp and the start value (let progress .... el.textcontent), overwriting whatever change you made in the button click handler.  You might want to change the value of start when the button is changed rather than changing the innerHTML in order to get it to work.

Comment: you mean to this??

Comment: const kashefButton= document.getElementById("btn3");
kashefButton.addEventListener("click", kashef);


 function kashef(){

start=200

}